# Magento 2 How to validate new Billing address form in checkout page

Tags: form-validation, billing-address, checkout-page

Here in new Billing address form in checkout page I have fields of Zip/Postal Code, and Phone number. I added Validation for those two working fine. But its getting saved if they are Empty. How to make the form should not submit if they are Empty.

```
MyVendor/MyModule/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
            <referenceBlock  name="checkout.root">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="firstname" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="letters-only" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                            <item name="no-whitespace" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>                    
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="lastname" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="letters-only" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                            <item name="no-whitespace" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                                            <item name="custom_pincode_validation" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                         <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">100</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="city" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">101</item>
                                                                    </item>

                                                                    <item name="region_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">102</item>
                                                                    </item>

                                                                    <item name="company" xsi:type="array">...</item>
                                                                    <item name="fax" xsi:type="array">...</item>
                                                                    <item name="country_id" xsi:type="array">...</item>
                                                                    <item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                            <item name="mobileIN" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Here is the Validation file

```
    app/code/MyVendor/BillingInfoForm/Plugin/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php

<?php
namespace MyVendor\BillingInfoForm\Plugin\Block\Checkout;
use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor as MageLayoutProcessor;

class LayoutProcessor
{
    public function afterProcess(MageLayoutProcessor $subject, $jsLayout)
    {


        /* config: checkout/options/display_billing_address_on = payment_method */
        if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children']
        )) {

            foreach ($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                     ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'] as $key => $payment) {

                /* postcode */
                if (isset($payment['children']['form-fields']['children']['postcode'])) {

                    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                    ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$key]['children']['form-fields']['children']
                    ['postcode'] =  [
                        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/post-code',
                        'config' => [
                            'customScope' => 'billingingAddress',
                            'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                            'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
                            'options' => [],
                            'id' => 'postcode'
                        ],
                        'dataScope' => 'billingingAddress.postcode',
                        'label' => 'Zip/Postal Code',
                        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                        'visible' => true,
                        'validation' =>["required-entry" => true, "min_text_length" =>6,
                        "max_text_length" =>6,"no-whitespace"=> true,"validate-number"=>true],
                        'sortOrder' => 100,
                        'id' => 'postcode'
                    ];
                }

                /* city */
                if (isset($payment['children']['form-fields']['children']['city'])) {

                    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                    ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$key]['children']['form-fields']['children']
                    ['city']['sortOrder'] = 101;


                }
                if (isset($payment['children']['form-fields']['children']['region_id'])) {

                    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                    ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$key]['children']['form-fields']['children']
                    ['region_id']['sortOrder'] = 102;

                }
                 if (isset($payment['children']['form-fields']['children']['country_id'])) {

                    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                    ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$key]['children']['form-fields']['children']
                    ['country_id']['sortOrder'] = 103;

                }

                /* telephone */
                if (isset($payment['children']['form-fields']['children']['telephone'])) {

                $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$key]['children']['form-fields']['children']
                ['telephone'] =  [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'billingingAddress',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
                    'options' => [],
                    'id' => 'telephone'
                ],
                'dataScope' => 'billingingAddress.telephone',
                'label' => 'Phone Number',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'visible' => true,
                'validation' =>['required-entry' => true, "min_text_length" => 10,
                "max_text_length" => 10,"no-whitespace"=> true,"validate-number"=>true],
                'sortOrder' => 104,
                'id' => 'telephone'
            ];

            }   
        }

        return $jsLayout;
    }
  }
}
```

Can I get help?. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The attribute validation check is based on the bool value **"is_required"** in table **"Eav Attribute"**.

Set the attribute `is_required` = '1' for mandate fields Zip/Postal Code & Phone number

```
UPDATE `eav_attribute` SET `is_required` = '1' WHERE `eav_attribute`.`attribute_code` = 'phone_number';
```

Comment: For `phone_number` `is_required` is already 1, and i update for postcode but still it saving with empty value.

Comment: Did u clear the cache. php bin/magento cache:flush or  php bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: Thank you for responce @Bala Varadarajan, Yes I DId cache:flush and cache:clear, but still not working.